# CDF and cumsum of a prbabolity density function

Tags: density-function, cumulative-distribution-functions

This is a really really stupid question, but why when I plot a CDF and `cumsum` of a PDF (e.g. exponential):

$$
f(t) ~ = \lambda e^{-\lambda t}, ~~~ t \ge 0
$$

I get the following plot:

[image]

This is the code for the CDF and cumsum values:

```
x = np.linspace(0, 5, 100)
y = l*np.exp(-l*x)

cumsum = np.cumsum(y)
cdf = 1 - np.exp(-l*x)
```

The `cumsum` goes way above 1 (as expected), however the CDF line reaches 1 as if a probability distribution was summed. Since the CDF is just an integral, which is sum, how can it differ from a cumulative sum over the y values?

Comment: It is off by a factor of 20, which is the step size of `x`. You could set `xmin=0`, `xmax=5`, and `n_points=100`, then `dx=(xmax-xmin)/n_points`, and finally multiply `cumsum` by `dx`.

Comment: @M.Nestor hey thanks for the quick reply. It does make sense under the definition of integrals, but I don't know why it feels so counterintuitive, that it integrates to 1. I would imagine if you have an infinite amount of points and sum them, that would be the same as integrating at a limit of `dx -> 0`, where you don't get the area anymore, but only height. I guess I don't understand integrals...

Comment: No. If we integrate a function that has values $f(x_i)$ we don't integrate it by summing those values. We sum $f(x_i)(x_i-x_{i-1})$. (Multiply by stepsize as @M.Nestor has pointed out.)